# How to getItems from localStorage saved by another process in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have been trying to develop an application in Nuxt 3, and i am very new to this Meta-Framework. While a user logs in, the API sends token in response and it is saved to localStorage using if(process.client), however once the login is completed, i need my homepage to get the token stored in localstorage and now i am getting LocalStorage undefined error on build. Below is my code for setItems and getItems

code for setItems

```js
methods: {
  async handleSubmit() {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', { email: this.email, password: this.password })

    console.log(response);
    notify({ title: response })

    if (process.client) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
    }
    this.$router.push('/')
  }
}
```

getItems code

```js
async created() {
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer' +  localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
  })
  console.log(response)
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`process.client` should probably not be needed here, because `handleSubmit` will probably be called upon a click or a user interaction.

Meanwhile, you could use `process.client` in your second snippet because `created` lifecycle hook is ran on both server and client side. And there is no such thing as `localStorage` in Node.js.

Or you could use `mounted`, which is [only called client-side](https://nuxtjs.org/pt/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client).

Comment: tried your suggestion, but its not working, as soon as i remove if case from my 1st snippet, the build fails with same error, localstorage not defined. moreover i am not able to find a way to put logic of If case inside headers in my 2nd snippet. could you help me with a code example if you might?